# Прервать цикл дойдя до блока в dom

Tags: javascript, dom

Помогите пожалуйста с идеей, есть верстка, в очень упрощенном виде так:

```
<body>
<div class="test">123</div>
<div class="test">123</div>
<div class="stop"></div>
<div class="test">123</div> 
</body>
```

нужно выполнить некое действие со всеми дивами с классом test , но только с теми, которые **выше** блока с классом stop, точное их количество неизвестно и будет меняться.

```
let test = document.querySelectorAll(".test");               
for (let i of test) {
i.innerHTML = i.innerHTML.replace('123', '321');
}
```

Что-то я не соображу ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let test = document.querySelectorAll(".test, .stop");
for (let i of test) {
  if (i.classList.contains("stop"))
    break;
  i.innerHTML = i.innerHTML.replace('123', '321');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="test">123</div>
  <div class="test">123</div>
  <div class="stop">STOP</div>
  <div class="test">123</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Я не очень умная ) Igor спасибо ❤ )

Comment: @МаринаНау На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: спасибо ) можно последний нубский вопросик, почему везде написано, что contains проверяет на вложенность .. в примере же тест не вложен в стоп, но все работает..

Comment: @МаринаНау contains, в данном случае, проверяет содержится ли определенный класс в псевдомасиве classList